# How to use a variable from another c file in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, variables, linux-kernel

I know the way normal and I tried it but it seems not work.

In linux/net/sched/sch_htb.c, I define the variable:

```
unsigned int queuelength;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(queuelength);
```

And some actions about the variable, not important.

In linux/net/ipv4/tcp_dctcp.c,

```
extern unsigned int queuelength;
```

Error come with net/built-in.o:

```
In function `dctcp_update_alpha':
linux/net/ipv4/tcp_dctcp.c:230: undefined reference to `queuelength'
```

The kernel version is v4.6.

Comment: Are both files (`net/sched/sch_htb.c` and `net/ipv4/tcp_dctcp.c`) are compiled as a **part of the kernel core** (that is, not as modules)? If so, no `EXPORT_SYMBOL` is needed. Note, that compilation of the file `sched/sch_htb.c` depends on `CONFIG_NET_SCH_HTB` configuration option. If you compile it as a module, you cannot use symbol defined in it in the kernel core.

Comment: I checked the '.config' file, which shows"CONFIG_TCP_CONG_DCTCP=y
" and "CONFIG_NET_SCH_HTB=m". I think that maybe I should change it from 'm' to 'y' and delete the 'EXPORT_SYMBOL'.Then I can compile it successfuly?

Comment: I have another question. I need to use the variable 'queuelength' also in other codes (ovs). So maybe I have to reserve 'EXPORT_SYMBOL' and compilation as module?I'm not sure about it but it did work well without modifying net/ipv4/tcp_dctcp.c.What should I do to deal with the both problems at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how a source file, which *defines* the variable (generally, symbol), and a source file, which *uses* the variable (symbol) are compiled: as a part of the **kernel module**, or as a part of the **kernel core** (that is, *built-in* into kernel).

Assuming names of the source files are `define-symbol.c` and `use-symbol.c` correspondingly, you have 5 possibilities:

1. Both `define-symbol.c` and `use-symbol.c` are compiled into **kernel core**.

   `EXPORT_SYMBOL` *isn't needed*.
2. `define-symbol.c` is compiled into **kernel core**, `use-symbol.c` is compiled into **kernel module**.

   `EXPORT_SYMBOL` is *needed*.
3. `define-symbol.c` is compiled into **kernel module**, `use-symbol.c` is compiled into **kernel core**.

   You *cannot use* such symbol.
4. `define-symbol.c` and `use-symbol.c` are compiled into the **same kernel module**.

   `EXPORT_SYMBOL` *isn't needed*.
5. `define-symbol.c` and `use-symbol.c` are compiled into the **different kernel modules**.

   `EXPORT_SYMBOL` is *needed*.

Note, that way of source compilation may *depend on configuration options*.

In your case, it seems you have situation 3: as `net/ipv4/tcp_dctcp.c` is used for `built-in.o`, it is part of the *kernel core*.

---

Note, that in any case variable should be **declared** for use it. Otherwise, it will be *compile-time error*, not a link one.